# Weak WiFi signal in Ubuntu on HP G240 G5

Tags: wireless, hp, signal

I had purchased new HP 240 G5 laptop. Wifi is working good with windows but in ubuntu 16 wifi signal comes very weak. Below are laptop wifi details,

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.178 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1000000-c1003fff
```

Comment: Is it Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu 16.10 ?

Answer (score 2):

First installing Realtek wifi driver in ubuntu, use below commnad for the same.

```
#sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
#git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
#cd rtlwifi_new
#make
#sudo make install
#sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

Disable wifi power saving mode by below command.

```
#sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
and type below parameter in to above file.
options rtl8723be fwlps=0
```

Now test wifi that on which slot it is working good by below commands,

```
#sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
#sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
#iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
```

or for slot 2

```
#sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
#sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
#iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
```

If it is working on slot one,run below command,

```
#echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
and If ant_sel=2 was better, then
#echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

At last reboot the system
`#sudo reboot`.
DONE!

For more refer http://www.syshunt.com/hp-ubuntu-16-linux-mint-weak-wifi-signal-problem/

Comment: Are you going to reveal your association to syshunt.com?  That kernel does not need the lwfinger rtlwifi_new as it already has the ant_sel parameter

Comment: What is the real source of info for the answer as it is very strange that the info was put on the linked website just a half hour before you posted this here